# .net HttpClient(Factory) inject subset of HttpMessageHandlers

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient

Referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Using the standard pattern of HttpClientFactory, I can inject an HttpClient into MyApiClient.  The application's setup code can configure the HttpClient with a lot of bells and whistles that the application cares about (lifetime, retry policies, etc).

What if I want some of the HttpMessageHandlers to be provided by MyApiClient?

One such use-case would be for exception handling.  I could implement a HttpMessageHandler that checks the response status code and throws exceptions.  Doing that with an HttpMessageHandler saves a lot of boiler-plate code in all of the places that a request is made.  Another use-case might be to add standard headers that MyApiClient knows about, like user-agent.

Expecting the consuming application to be kind enough to add the handlers expected by MyApiClient (perhaps required to make the requests) doesn't strike me as the best approach, but it's the only real option I see at the moment.

Curious if others have struggled with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient has the concept of delegating handlers that can be linked together for outgoing HTTP requests. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1
You can provide a mechanism to manage cross-cutting concerns around HTTP requests, such as:

- caching
- error handling
- serialization
- logging

Comment: Handler order sometimes matters.  As such, I don't think this approach is entirely feasible.